# Recording audio and video efficiently in google chrome extension without media server

Tags: javascript, audio, video

I am working on a project for recording audio and video using browser. We already have an implementation using flash and media server. But problem with that is this does not handle packet drops. Now we are thinking of creating chrome extension for this where we record and save locally and then sync to server. For that after searching I found one approach where we get audio and video file separately using Muaz khans web rtc experiment and merged that into .mp4 file usinf ffmpeg js. But that could be very heavy task. I also thought of doing ffmpeg conversion on some other server. But for that we would need to upload the audio and video file from client. And the audio and video files I am getting are very large. Is there some other more eficient approach for this? Maybe some way to record audio in ogg and video in some more efficient format. Right now I capture audio in wav and video in webm format.

Comment: Please share more details of what you have tried

Comment: I have a sample implementation where I have created a chrome extension and in that I use Webkit getUserMedia to capture audio and video. I then use Whammy encoder to encode that into a .webm file (video) and .wav file (audio). Then I use ffmpeg.js to merge these into a .mp4 file. But this is a slow process. Also this is high memory consuming. The audio and video files obtained are also very high size audio(10-15 MB, video 20-30 MB). So I cannot first record audio and video in browser and send the files for merger on remote server.

Comment: The .mp4 file that I obtain using ffmpeg.js is of the order of around 10 MB which is manageable and could also be further reduced with lowering the bit rates. But again this is a heavy task to be done in browser. Would be best we could directly convert the streams into format like .mp4 instead of first encoding into wav for audio and webm for video and then merging them.